# Merging two data frames in R and returning all data

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to merge two `data.frame`s in R. I have the following:

```
final <- merge(data1,data2,by=c('id'))
```

I get the message:

> Warning: only first 100,000 results retrieved. Use `n=-1` to retrieve all.

When I do that:

```
final <- merge(data1,data2,by=c('id'),n=-1)
```

The results are the same with the same warning. Is there any way to retrieve all of the columns?

Comment: Have you tried `collect(final)` after running your first listed `merge` command?  I believe this should retrieve all of your results

Comment: I just tried your suggestion. Same result.

Comment: Can you give more information about the data frames?  Maybe a `str(data1)` and `str(data2)` -- I don't see this behavior with a toy example with 200,000 rows

Comment: One is a data frame, the other one is sqlite table

Comment: Michael; Saying that one is a dataframe and one an sqlite table is pointing the finger at sqlite as the problem. You really should respond more completely to @user295691. You now need to post the code along with needed `library` calls to set up a working environment for testing. AND DO IT AS AN EDIT.

Comment: From various hints, I am deducing that you are using `dplyr` to do this whole shebang.  In that case, you simply need to do `collect(data1)` (or data2 -- whichever is the sqlite one).  The warning you are seeing is coming from the `dbFetch` command in `DBI`; I don't know that there's a way to make `as.data.frame.tbl_sql` pass the parameter through.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following before merge.

```
data1 <- collect(data1)
data2 <- collect(data2)
```